# jQuery show/hide is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following loop in php:

```
foreach ($sid as $key => $value) {
    $sql = " a sql query ";
    $vehicle->rowQuery($sql);
    $numRows = $vehicle->rows;

        while ( $data = $vehicle->result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $vid            = $data['vid'];
            $vehicleName    = $data['vehicleName'];
            $noOfSeat       = $data['noOfSeat'];
            $seatBooked     = $data['seatBooked'];
            $supplierName   = $data['supplierName'];

            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th colspan='4' class='success'>
                    <label class='checkbox-inline'>
                    <input type='checkbox' class='vehicleClass' name='vid[]' value='{$vid}'>$vehicleName<strong> ( $noOfSeat Seats available) - $supplierName
                    </label>
                    <div class='pull-right'><a href='#' class='hideMe'>Show/Hide</a></div></strong>&nbsp;
                    <input type='hidden' name='noOfSeat[$vid]' value='$noOfSeat'>
                    </th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th colspan='4'>All Seats</th>";
                echo "</tr>";

                $count = 0;
                for ($seat=1; $seat <= $noOfSeat; $seat++) {

                    if($count % 4 == 0) {
                        echo "</tr><tr class='toggleMe'>";
                    }
                    echo "<td><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='seatNo[$vid][]' value='$seat'>Seat $seat </label></td>";

                    $count++;
                }
            echo "</table>";
        }

    if( $numRows == 0 ) {
        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped'>";
        echo '<tr><td class="alert alert-warning">Your selected vehicle is not available.</td></tr>';
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

It's output is like that:

[image]

Now, I am trying to show and hide the corresponding **All Seats** Checkbox list whne I click on **show/hide** link using following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hideMe').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.toggleMe').toggle();
    });
});
```

But show/hide it's not working. Can you guys tell me how can I solve it?

Thanks.

===================

## **Update:**

When the loop result is this :

[image]

then using this code it's working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hideMe').click(function() {
        $('.toggleMe').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you got any error on console?

Comment: It's just showing me: Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: Did you checked that line?

Comment: I just set an alert message for testing purpose when I click on that link. It's showing alert message.

Comment: @KiranShahi do you think that is the issue?

Comment: @Shibbir Can you create JsFiddle with your problem, please. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: might be. Can you make working snippet ?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: Guys, you can see that I have all PHP code. How can I create jsfiddle :(

Comment: @Shibbir simply show me how your html structure looks like.

Comment: Convert PHP to html, you can see html part in your console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use ajax to get the html?
if yes, you had better use `$('body').on('click,'.hideMe',function() {})`
and `tr` is not next element of `.hideMe`
You can try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.hideMe',function() {
        $(this).parents('table').find('.toggleMe').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, the HTML is coming from ajax.

Comment: Great, It's working but why I should use the parents?

Comment: OH I got it.. :)

Comment: @Shibbir since your dom is dynamically created. You need static element to search dynamically created element.

Comment: @Bai Nguyen, I have some issue. The html is coming when I click on the checkbox. Now show/hide is working when I click on the checkbox twice!! Can you tell me why?

Comment: "why I should use the parents" Because your have many tables created in your loop, and you want toggle 'toggleMe' in the table contain '.hideme' clicked. 
"Can you tell me why?"  could you pls comment code at here. glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `on('Click',function(){ })` instead of `click` try this

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.hideMe', function() {
        $(this).next('.toggleMe').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your structuring with "`<tr>`" is not correct in

`if($count % 4 == 0) {
   echo "</tr><tr class='toggleMe'>";
}`

this will add a `</tr>` at the beginning of each toggleMe class.